# Is it possible to avoid subquery in select when concatenating columns?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a "main" table containing an id (plus some other columns) and an aka table which joins to it by the [main id] column to main.id. The following query returns some columns from main along with a column of concatenated comma-separated "lastName"s from aka:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
   (SELECT a.[lastname] + ',' AS [text()] 
    FROM   aka a 
    WHERE  a.[main id] = m.[id] 
    FOR xml path ('')) [akas] 
FROM   main m
```

This works fine, but I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid doing this in a subquery?

Comment: without using sub query, you may still need to join the 2 tables before finally selecting on the result.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot join main with aka? what is special so you are using for xml path?

Comment: You could create your own CLR aggregate and then it would be a normal `group by` with no subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY` you could move subquery from `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, 
   (SELECT a.[lastname] + ',' AS [text()] 
    FROM   aka a 
    WHERE  a.[main id] = m.[id] 
    FOR xml path ('')) [akas] 
FROM   main m;
```

to:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, s.akas
FROM   main m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT a.[lastname] + ',' AS [text()] 
             FROM   aka a 
             WHERE  a.[main id] = m.[id] 
             FOR xml path ('')) AS s(akas)
```

Notes:

- You could refer to s.akas multiple time
- You could add `WHERE s.akas ...`
- Long subquery in `SELECT` list could be less readable
- If it is possbile that correlated subquery return no rows you need to use `OUTER APPLY` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Generally spoken there's nothing against a sub-query in a technical view...

You might prefer an `APPLY` due to readability or multi reference.

Whenever you put a sub-query directly into the column's list like here:

```
SELECT Column1
      ,Column2
      ,(SELECT x FROM y) AS Column3
      ,[...]
```

... this sub-select must deliver

- just one column
- of just one row

Using `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE` lets the result be one single value of type XML. This makes it possible to return many rows/columns "as one". Without the `,TYPE` it will be the XML "as text". The concatenation trick with XML is possible due to a speciality of the generation of XML with empty tag names and return "as text". But in any case: The returned value will be just one bit of information, therefore fitting into a column list.

Whenever you expect more than one row, you'd have to force this to be one bit of data (like - often seen! - `SELECT TOP 1 x FROM y ORDER BY SomeSortKey`, which brings back the first or the last or ...)

All other intentions to get 1:n data needs 'JOIN' or 'APPLY'. With scalar data, as in your case, there will actually be no difference, whether you use a sub-select or an `APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an arbitrary number of records combining for the final string, what you have is the best option to do this in SQL. Generally, you are expected to return one row per item, and if you want a CSV string then build that in your client code.